# Tabulator table empty after loading from html table

Tags: html, load

I have loaded an html table from a csv file and see on the page and when I inspect it using developer tools, it looks well formatted. When I issue this command:

var tabTbl = new Tabulator("#example-table", {})

The table turns greyed and is empty when I inspect it in the browser. Here is the code which loads the table, which is in good form with thead and tbody sections :

```
 var rows = fileContents.split("\n")
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        var header = table.createTHead();
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",")
                        if (cells.length > 1) {

                            var row = header.insertRow(-1)
                            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                                cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                            }
                        }
                        continue
                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                        body = table.createTBody();
                    
                    var cells = rows[i].split(",")
                    if (cells.length > 1) {
                        var row = body.insertRow(-1)
                        for (var k = 0; k < cells.length; k++) {
                            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                            cell.innerHTML = cells[k];
                        }
                    }
                }
                fileContentDiv.innerHTML = ""
                fileContentDiv.appendChild(table)
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How are you loading this html table from a csv?

Comment: I am using a file reader:

Comment: When I comment out the line which instantiates tabulator, after building the html table, I inspect the table with id "example-table and it has a thead section with column headers and tbody section with the data.